# Naming names and שמירת הלשון

Tags: lashon-hara-slander, halacha

Is there a documented basis in *halacha* for the commonly held concept that no damage is done by slandering people without naming them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Sefer Ikrei Dinim in the back of the Chofetz Chaim (Klal 3 Number 19 Note 1) the Chofetz Chaim discusses this. The Chofetz Chaim says that if the purpose of doing this is in order for others to learn from it and he is certain that no one will know whom he is discussing then it is permissible. However the person has to be extra careful that no one should ever be able to figure out who he is talking about as often with time people do figure out who was discussed and then you were Oiver the Issur.